# emacs frame-title-format doesn't keep the file name present in the task bar

Tags: windows, emacs

I have noticed this behavior after I upgraded to emacs 24.3. I haven't changed my `.emacs` file.

I have the line

```
(setq frame-title-format "%b")
```

This allows my filename to be the default name of the emacs icon in my taskbar and is very useful in identifying whichever file is open. However I have noticed that now the emacs icon keeps reverting to the default `"emacs@computer_name"` title.

As you can imagine this is quite aggravating so any insight will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I can provide any further information.

Edit:My system is a 64bit Windows 7 Professional

Comment: You should specify your system. My system, for instance, doesn't even have a task bar.

Comment: I think his system was implied from the [Windows] tag. :-)

Comment: @Bruce Connor: Thanks for pointing out the Windows tag.

Comment: @abo-abo: Thanks for the input, I've made the edit to clearly state the system.

Comment: Has the answer posted by sds been working so far?

Comment: @BruceConnor: It has been working so far, I wanted to give it some more time before confirming. I think icon-title-format has fixed it.

Comment: Don't worry, I wasn't complaining, I was just curious. :-)

Comment: Just adding that I had a similar/same problem on linux. The title would first respect the "frame-title-format", but then would just randomly change to the "icon-title-format"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the icon title is controlled by [`icon-title-format`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle), not `frame-title-format`.

Comment: Well it's not that the icon doesn't get the correct, It's that the icon does not retain the name like it used to earlier. I have made the change with the line:

(setq frame-title-format 
      (setq icon-title-format "%b"))

Let's see if it works.

Comment: I haven't encountered the problem ever since I added icon-title-format. So i think that has fixed the issue. Thank you for the solution.